# Нехватка регистров ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

Была поставлена следующая задача:

Создать целочисленный массив A[1..k] и число М. Найти такое множество элементов A[ i+1 ], A[ i+2 ], . . . ,A[ i+l ], что A[ i+1 ]+A[ i+2 ]+...+A[ i+l ]=M. Если такого множества подряд идущих чисел нет, то сообщить об этом.

Написала программу на встроенном ассемблере:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a[10], n, m, i0 = 0, s = 0, i1 = 0, j1 = 0;

    printf_s("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf_s("Enter the number M: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf_s("Enter the elements of array A: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
    }   

    __asm
    {
        xor eax, eax
        xor dx, dx
        lea esi, a
        mov ecx, n
        c1:
             inc i0
             inc i1
             add eax, [esi]
             mov ebx, [esi]
              cmp ebx, m
            je rav
              cmp ebx, m
            jg bolshe
             add esi, 4 
            jmp end
            rav:
                 mov j1, i
                 exitc1: loop c1
            bolshe:
                xor ebx, ebx
                xor i0, i0
            end: 
                nop
        loop c1

        mov s, eax
        mov i1, i0
    }

     if (s == m)
    {
        printf_s("Takoe mnogestvo est' ");
        printf_s("%d", a[j1 - i1 + 1]);
        for (i = j1 - i1 + 2; i <= j1; i++)
        {
            printf_s(" + %d", a[i]);
        }

        printf_s(" = %d", m);

    }
    else printf_s("Takogo mnogestva net"); 
    _getch();
}
```

Проблема в том, что для счетчиков i1 и j1 регистров не хватает.

Код на С, реализующий тоже самое, что и на ассемблере:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    i1++;
    s += a[i];
    if (s == m) 
    { 
        j1 = i;
        break;
    }
    if (s > m)
    {
        s = 0;
        i1 = 0;
    }
}
```

Прошу помочь разобраться, что можно сделать. Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: для начала можно запустить C программу в отладчике и посмотреть на неё в окне дизассемблера

Comment: Что то я не вижу, что бы вы где то использовали edx и edi. Их можно использовать. P.S. cmp ebx, m два раза делать не обязательно. инструкция cmp выставляет флаги и вы их можете использовать в нескольких последующих инструкциях, т.е. спокойно писать подряд je и jg

Comment: Если и после этого регистров не хватает, можно использовать ebp. Он конечно указатель стека и надо его сохранить в начале и восстановить в конце и вроде как не очень принято его использовать как регистр общего назначения, но и не то что бы нельзя это было делать

Comment: @Mike , а получается, для использования регистра ebp нужно использовать команды push и pop?

Comment: нет, обычными mov. это дополнительный регистр для удобства работы со стеком. сами push/pop на него никак не влияют. просто если вдруг напишите mov eax, [ebp] будет подразумеваться mov eax, ss:[ebp], т.е. по умолчанию он считается смещением в сегменте стека